# Filter file with findstr or awk and sed

Tags: awk, sed, findstr

I am trying to filter this file based on the backslash before a semicolon, for example filter the file below to obtain the lines that contain up to six backslashes before a semicolon

```
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI (0x03);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Thumbs.db;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\SametimeChatHistory\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\eduardo.id;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
```

Desired output

```
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI (0x03);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Thumbs.db;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
```

I tried to run

```
    findstr /r "\\\\.*\\.*\\.*\\;" 

    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI (0x03);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\SametimeChatHistory\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
```

But it doesn't work, it brings more lines than what I wanted, if anyone has any other idea with either windows findstr or awk / sed I will appreciate it

Comment: You may want to provide more information such as what environment you are working in so that others may attempt to reproduce. Also, provide the error that you are getting when you attempt to run `findstr /r "\\\\.*\\.*\\.*\\;"`

Comment: In  your desired output, the first two lines have only five backslashes before the semikolon.

Comment: @Daniel I updated the ask with the result of findstr. The environment is Windows 10 or 7, I am also using awk and sed ports.

Comment: @vaettchen yes I will update the question, I wanted to see any line that has slashes let's say from 1 to 6 and not just six before the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show lines with six backslashes only before first semicolon. Change the `==` in the if statement to `<=` if need to keep all lines less than or equal to 6 before the semicolon.

```
$ awk -F';'  '{if (split($1,a,"\\") == 7) print $0;}' test
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\eduardo.id;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
```

As pointed out by @Ed Morton in the comments below this can be simplified to just

```
awk -F';'  'split($1,a,/\\/) <= 7' test
```

Comment: `'{if (split($1,a,"\\") == 7) print $0;}'` in idiomatic awk is just `'split($1,a,/\\/) == 7'`. The 3rd arg for spit is a regexp btw, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F';' '{k=$1} gsub(/\\/,"",k)<=6' file
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI (0x03);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Thumbs.db;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\My Documents\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:OI,CI,IA (0x13)
    \\Filehomeserver\homefolder\eduardo\Notes ID file\eduardo.id;USDOM\eduardo : Allowed CHGE:EWXD (0x001301BF) Flags:IA (0x10);USDOM\sec_&Conf_group: Allowed FULL:EWXPOD (0x001F01FF) Flags:IA (0x10)
```